# É possível conectar uma aplicação feita em C a algum banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, sql, c, banco-de-dados, conexão

Normalmente utilizamos arquivos para salvar dados utilizando linguagem *C* (eu pelo menos). É possível conectar um banco de dados relacional a alguma aplicação feita em *C*? Se sim, é preciso alguma biblioteca para isso e como é feita essa conexão? Preferencialmente MySQL.

Comment: Sim, só isso que quer saber?

Comment: Gostaria de saber como fazer a conexão.

Comment: Em qual banco de dados?

Comment: Qualquer banco relacional, preferencialmente mySql

Comment: De uma olhada neste [artigo](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por que não teria como?

Linguagens de programação são apenas mecanismos para se comunicar com o computador. O que faz a comunicação com bancos de dados são códigos geralmente organizados em bibliotecas. Cada banco de dados fornece sua maneira de fazer isso. Muitos banco de dados são escritos em C então é bem direto. Em outras linguagens que costuma ter alguma camada de adaptação.

Exemplo no MySQL:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main() {
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (con == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(1);
    }
    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "root", "root_pswd", NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE DATABASE testdb")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        mysql_close(con);
        exit(1);
    }
    mysql_close(con);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/MySql.c).

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api.html).

[Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/).

Answer (score 2):

Sim tem como, o Postgresql mesmo usa muitas funções em C e possui uma library pra isso. Basta add **#include**

Você vai precisar descobrir onde se encontra o arquivo libpq-fe.h, depois, ao compilar o programa, passamos o diretório acima dentro da opção -I do gcc: 
 gcc -o programa -I/usr/include/pgsql programa.c -lpq

Isso supondo que a sua biblioteca está em /usr/include/pgsql. Altere para o diretório onde se encontra a sua. Talvez seja necessário utilizar a opção -L e o diretório, ao invés da opção -I.

Maiores detalhes em:
fonte [viva o linux](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Acessando-PostgreSQL-com-C/?pagina=4)